# Jenkins Pipeline status FAILURE when build job is UNSTABLE

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using pipeline with few stages.

Currently my pipeline fails because one of the stages is UNSTABLE.

In the specific stage, I execute external job by "build job".

The job is Publish MSTest test results and when having failed tests, the job is UNSTABLE.

Why it cause the pipeline to fails?

How can I force the pipeline to end successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
 build(
    job: "your_job",
    propagate: false
```

)

to ignore the failing job

Comment: How can I do the same without `build` step? I mean I have several stages, one of them is unstable, but I'd like to mark a pipeline as `SUCCESS`

Comment: I not sure what your are intending to do, but if you put that on every build step your pipeline is always green.